# regex to filter everything except whats in test resources

Tags: ruby, regex

My git server has this as the push filter

```
^(?!.*gradle-wrapper\.jar$).*\.(?:jar|exe|a|ar|cpio|shar|iso|LBR|lbr|mar|sbx|tar|bz2|F|gz|lz|lzma|lzo|rz|sfark|sz|xz|z|Z|7z|s7z|ace|afa|alz|apk|arc|arj|b1|ba|bh|cab|car|cfs|cpt|dar|dd|dgc|dmg|ear|gca|ha|hki|ice|kgb|lzh|lha|lzx|pak|partimg|paq6|paq7|paq8|pea|pim|pit|qda|rar|rk|sda|sea|sen|sfx|shk|sit|sitx|sqx|tar.gz|tgz|tar.Z|tar.bz2|tbz2|tar.lzma|tlz|uc|uc0|uc2|ucn|ur2|ue2|uca|uha|war|wim|xar|xp3|yz1|zip|zipx|zoo|zpaq|zz|dll)$
```

Basically, we don't want archives pushed to the server.  This is fine, but, i was just given a valid argument that archives in the test resources should be permitted.  So given this test set

```
bla.zip
/gradle/gradle-wrapper.jar
myproject/src/test/resources/testjar.ear
herproject/src/test/resources/testjar.ear
src/main/resources/testjar.ear
```

The only matches should be `src/main/resources/testjar.ear` and `bla.zip`.  If the file is preceded by the sequence `src/test/resources` it should be valid and not match.  I'm not that good with regex, could someone help me out here?  The git server is gitlab and this regex is in ruby.

http://rubular.com/r/MssVyALeCO is the rubular

Comment: Try appending [`(?!(?:.*\/)?src\/test\/resources(?:\/|$))` right after `^`](http://rubular.com/r/HIDNcSd09h). Or, maybe `(?!(?:.*\/)?src\/test\/resources\/[^\/]+$)` or `(?!(?:.*\/)?src\/test\/resources\/[^\/]*$)`

Comment: that seems to have done it.  thanks

Comment: Ok, I posted the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add the `(?!(?:.*\/)?src\/test\/resources(?:\/|$))` negative lookahead to the pattern:

```
^(?!(?:.*\/)?src\/test\/resources(?:\/|$))(?!.*gradle-wrapper\.jar$).*\.(?:jar|exe|a|ar|cpio|shar|iso|LBR|lbr|mar|sbx|tar|bz2|F|gz|lz|lzma|lzo|rz|sfark|sz|xz|z|Z|7z|s7z|ace|afa|alz|apk|arc|arj|b1|ba|bh|cab|car|cfs|cpt|dar|dd|dgc|dmg|ear|gca|ha|hki|ice|kgb
```

See the [Rubular demo](http://rubular.com/r/HIDNcSd09h)

**NOTE**: If you need to match the actual *start of the string*, replace `^` with `\A` and for *end of string*, replace `$` with `\z` (in Ruby, `^`/`$` match the start/end of the *line* by default).

The `(?!(?:.*\/)?src\/test\/resources(?:\/|$))` lookahead fails the match if the following pattern is found at the start of the input:

- `(?:.*\/)?` - any 0+ chars, as many as possible, followed with `/`
- `src\/test\/resources` - a literal string `src/test/resources`
- `(?:\/|$)` - `/` or end of string.